# Golang Google Admin SDK API Client not setting boolean properties correctly

Tags: go, google-admin-sdk

I am using golang package google.golang.org/api/admin/directory/v1 v0.28.0 to build an administrator CLI for Google G Suite.

The User type (and other types as well) has boolean properties with omitempty json tags. I can set these properties to a value of true, but when I try to set them to false, nothing happens. I believe that this is because the omitempty option means that the value false is ignored when passed.

After a bit of web research, it seems that the answer might be to use pointers and change the type of the boolean properties from bool to *bool. Then set the value by using a bool pointer like this:

```
user := new(*admin.User)

f := new(bool)
*f = false
user.Suspended = f
```

I'm not sure why this might work, but it was suggested and confirmed as working in respect of another API.

These API client libraries are auto-generated and I'm not sure how I can test my theory. If anyone has come across this issue in the past, is there a remedy or workaround for it? Could anyone suggest how I can generate my own version of the golang client?

Comment: I do not use Go and you do not provide your full code, but you cannot change user properties by just assigning variables. You need to call the respective Google API method, for example [Users: update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update). You need to specify a key-value pair within th request body of this method, e.g. `"suspended": false`  and then execute the request (with a `Do()` in Go).Test your request with `Try this API` before implementing it in Go based on the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/go)

Comment: I got an answer which worked for me. A comment from the code explains the use of ForceSendFields which was the solution -

ForceSendFields is a list of field names (e.g. "Addresses") to
unconditionally include in API requests. By default, fields with
empty values are omitted from API requests. However, any non-pointer,
non-interface field appearing in ForceSendFields will be sent to the
server regardless of whether the field is empty or not. This may be
used to include empty fields in Patch requests.

Comment: @ChrisDuncan Thank you for this! I was trying to unarchive a user by just sending `&admin.User{Archived: false}` and it wasn't doing anything. It works if I send `ForceSendFields` along with it. Maybe it sees only boolean false attrs as "empty" and omits them?